# Pull info using a servlet and display on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm not sure if this is the correct terminology but I want to pull some information from a servlet and display it onto my JSP page.

This is what I'm using in the servlet:

```js
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
  response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
  try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
    /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Servlet AccountLookupServlet</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    String i, id, typ;
    double bal;
    i = request.getParameter("custid");
    try {
      Account c1 = new Account();
      c1.selectDB(i);
      id = c1.getCid();
      typ = c1.getType();
      bal = c1.getBalance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
  }
}
```

What this servlet is doing is simply get a user id from the main jsp page and then run an object which connects to the database and pulls out all the required information. All this is working sweet. Now by pull, what I mean is that when the user clicks the lookup button on main jsp, it should run(not redirect) to servlet, the servlet will do all the above and then display the info it has obtained in the textboxes in the main jsp.

Thank you!

Comment: Yikes; HTML from a servlet?! *Uneasy flashbacks* What's the issue? If you have the account, use the exact same stuff you've been doing to output the information however you want it displayed. Then stop doing that and use, say, a JSP.

Comment: Yes I have the account and all that information is stored within the servlet. However what I want is that when the user clicks the button on the JSP, It should run the servlet and the info that it stores would be displayed in the textboxes in the JSP page. In other words the user would never see the servlet.

Comment: A user never "sees" a servlet in the first place. Are you asking how to retrieve the information via Ajax (e.g., JavaScript), and update the page in-place?!

Comment: I guess yes, I'm asking for the code to run the servlet from within the JSP

Comment: You don't "run the servlet" from within the JSP; you make an HTTP request, take the output, and use JS to do something useful with the HTTP response. You'll likely want to use a JS library for this, jQuery is ubiquitous, but not the only choice. Searching the web for jQuery Ajax tutorials will get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I didn't want to use AJAX to produce results, as that was not required by my project but I guess that method works. After doing more research and talking to my professor, I came with the conclusion that you don't land on the same page after the info is pulled. You just create another page that uses identical setup with all the info that was pulled.

To the user it looks as if they are on same page but in fact they are on a new page that looks identical.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax to call the Servlet and get the data back silently. To do so it is a good idea to use JQuery ajax to do your bidding.

Here is an example of a GET request called on clicking a button:

```
       $('#button-id-goes-here').click(function ()
        {
            $.get( "your-url-for-servlet", function( data ) {
              // data is the response output from servlet
              $("#view-id-goes-here").html(data);
            });
        });
```

What this code does is simple. It calls the servlet URL when the button is clicked and then sets the response data in the view of a given id. Sets the data as HTML content here but you can play with the options.

Check this link:
[jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)